# Refers to 0 byte(s) beyond last valid byte in prior malloc

Tags: c, dr-memory

I seem to overwrite some parts of the memory in my C program unintentionaly. To fix this, I have downloaded DrMemory in good faith it will throw an error informing me about lines where this nastiness happens.
One of the first errors I ever get is this one:

```
~~Dr.M~~ Note: @0:00:00.802 in thread 7376
~~Dr.M~~ Note: refers to 0 byte(s) beyond last valid byte in prior malloc
~~Dr.M~~ Note: prev lower malloc:  0x00c00eb0-0x00c00eb4
~~Dr.M~~ Note: instruction: cmp    (%eax) $0x00
```

According to [the documantation](http://drmemory.org/docs/page_unaddr.html), it means that I tried to access the last byte of memory I have first allocated. How's that wrong?

Function that triggers the error:

```
void str_add_char(String* s, const char ch) {
  size_t length = s->length;
  if(length+1==s->size) {
    s->size+=s->size/2+1;
    s->c_str = (char*)realloc(s->c_str, s->size);  
  }
  s->c_str[length]=ch;
  s->c_str[length+1] = 0;
  s->length++;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the return-value of `realloc` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Also, how do you initialize the `String` to begin with (what are the values of `length` and `size`, and is `c_str` initialized with `malloc`)?

Comment: According to the error dump, the instruction faulted on is a compare not an assignment.   I'm not that good at reading intel assembly but is that a compare to zero?   The only compare I see in the snippet is in the if.    Is the structure S malloced?   Is s->size accessing off the end of it?   You might get better context for what the trap is by running gdb and disassembling the function at the address of the error.   I would presume that since it gave you the assembly at the trap,  that the tool would have also given you the instruction aaddress there.

Comment: Note: the `s->size += s->size/2+1;` will set the size to 1 of it was 0 before. `s->c_str[length+1] = 0;` will rhen write beyond the allocated area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realloc `s->size+1` -> the +1 accounts for the NULL terminator C uses to mark the end of the string.

Comment: there's a `s->size += /*something*/ +1`. In fact, I was rather curious about what the error means than what my particular problem is.

Comment: What the docs are saying (in a convoluted way) is that for each memory allocation extra bytes are allocated before the buffer returned to you (to detect underruns) and that extra bytes are also allocated after the buffer returned to you (to detect overruns). The example code in the docs demonstrates the problem `char *x = malloc(8);
char c = *(x+8);` since C arrays start from index zero, accessing the 8th byte is an overrun error - you are writing to memory you didn't allocate.

Comment: Sure, also the docs state that they such action produces an error that counts 1 byte overrun. So 0 bytes overrun sill makes no sense to me. Note that I'm having `0 byte(s) beyond last valid byte`.